# C# , MVC , EnityFramework , How to processing data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, string

I have this data

[image: data table]

I would to convert Day to English value
for example :
"السبت" = "saturday"
"الاحد" = "sunday"

this code :

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTime()
    {
        var data = _db.CourseTimes
     .GroupBy(c => c.Day)
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, v => v.Select(c => new { start = TimeSpan.FromHours(c.StartTime)
     .ToString("hh':'mm"), stop = TimeSpan.FromHours(c.EndTime).ToString("hh':'mm") }));

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

return this :

```
{"الاحد":[{"start":"01:00","stop":"02:00"},{"start":"01:00","stop":"02:00"},{"start":"14:00","stop":"20:00"}],"السبت":[{"start":"01:00","stop":"02:00"},{"start":"05:00","stop":"08:00"},{"start":"07:00","stop":"06:00"}]}
```

I want it to return this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is an implementation of how to do it:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTime()
{
    var english_names = (new CultureInfo("en-US")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames
        .Select((v, i) => new { Key = i, Value = v })
        .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);

    var arabic_names = (new CultureInfo("ar-EG")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames
        .Select((v, i) => new { Key = i, Value = v })
        .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);

    var data = _db.CourseTimes
        .GroupBy(c => c.Day)
        .ToDictionary(g => english_names.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == arabic_names.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == g.Key).Key).Value, v => v.Select(c => new
        {
            start = TimeSpan.FromHours(c.StartTime).ToString("hh':'mm"),
            stop = TimeSpan.FromHours(c.EndTime).ToString("hh':'mm")
        }).ToList());

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Basically, you just need to create two lists of names for each language and get the index of the english one for the arabic name, which is found on the second list.

Answer (score 0):

try using `CultureInfo`, or you must mapping the word into table or static list, and compare that word...